# Likelihood function of a sample selection model

Tags: maximum-likelihood, econometrics, tobit-regression

I'm having some problems with the following assignment:
I have a sample selection model (tobit II model) which however does not have the standard tobit II representation but rather the sample selection model is described by
y=1(xδ+u>0)e^(xb+e), where 1(.) is an indicator function taking the value of 1 if the argument in parenthesis is true, δ,β are coefficients and u, e are the residuals. The indicator function represents the sample selection issue. The standard tobit II model(truncation) is of the form y=1(xδ+u>0)(xb+e), thus without the exponential function. I am essentially asked to find the log likelihood of this model where truncation takes place and i am stuck. Essentially i am trying to find the pdf's from both the truncated part and the non truncated part of the model but so far it hasn't worked out.
If anyone could point me towards the right direction i'd really appreciate it!. Thanks in advance for any replies!

Answer (score 1):

This one was dubbed an Exponential Type II Tobit Model by Jeff Wooldridge. It's a bit too involved to reproduce here, but take a look at his [graduate text](http://books.google.com/books?id=yov6AQAAQBAJ&lpg=PA697&ots=iVmZAKFxXO&dq=jeff%20wooldridge%20exponential%20type%20II%20tobit&pg=PA697#v=onepage&q=jeff%20wooldridge%20exponential%20type%20II%20tobit&f=false) or [his lecture notes](http://www.iza.org/teaching/wooldridge-course-09/course_html/docs/slides_twopart_5_r1.pdf), and feel free to ask questions here if something is not clear.

Stata's `tpm` command by [Belotti, Deb, Manning and Norton](http://econ.hunter.cuny.edu/people/economics-faculty/pdeb/ihea-minicourse/tpm-estimating-two-part-models-working-paper/at_download/file) can handle this sort of thing quite nicely.